# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Get current location ( lat, long)

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-geolocation

I am working something with maps and not able to get the current location in worklight 6.0 any links or API which i can use to get current lat, long values.

Also i have seen this link for tracking the current location of device from IBM infocenter,

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fdevref%2Ft_tracking_devices.html

WL.Device.Geo.acquirePosition(onSuccess, onFailure, options)

How can i use the above api in my sample project, any suggestions,

Thanks 
djrecker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without your implementation and explanation of what you've tried to do, we cannot help you. This is a technical Q&A website...

Depending on what you're doing, you could:

- Use the [Cordova Geolocation API](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.6.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#Geolocation)

Or use the location services Worklight offers:

- Search for "location" in: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp
- Read the training material: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/09_07_Location_services.pdf

Please **read** what the two approaches offer and choose what's best for you.

Answer (score 0):

It is somewhat difficult to answer without a clear indication of what you're trying to accomplish.
One thing that you should be sure to validate is that your permissions are set appropriately (see http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_location.html ).

Using the WL.Device.Geo.acquirePosition(onSuccess, onFailure, options)  API can give you a single position (passed to the onSuccess function), to get at the longitude and latitude use position.coords.longitude and position.coords.latitude.

Use the WL.Device.startAcquisition API if you wish to track the location over time (as also shown in the short "how-to" you linked to).